# How to group FastAPI endpoints in Swagger UI?

Tags: python, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, fastapi

I started programming using FastAPI framework and it comes with a builtin Swagger interface to handle requests and responses.
I have completed nearly 20 APIs and its hard to manage and recognise APIs on Swagger interface.
Someone told me to add sections in Swagger interface to distinguish APIs, but I couldn't find any examples and I need help.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can add **tags** to your path parameter, for example.

If you have something like this, using tags is extremely helpful.

```
@app.delete("/items", tags=["Delete Methods"])
@app.put("/items", tags=["Put Methods"])
@app.post("/items", tags=["Post Methods"])
@app.get("/items", tags=["Get Methods"])
async def handle_items():
    return


@app.get("/something", tags=["Get Methods"])
async def something():
    return
```

[image]

You will get this, also if you want to add description and you don't want to keep repating yourself (For example adding same description in all parameters)

### You can use **openapi_tags** (I prefer this)

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

tags_metadata = [
    {"name": "Get Methods", "description": "One other way around"},
    {"name": "Post Methods", "description": "Keep doing this"},
    {"name": "Delete Methods", "description": "KILL 'EM ALL"},
    {"name": "Put Methods", "description": "Boring"},
]

app = FastAPI(openapi_tags=tags_metadata)


@app.delete("/items", tags=["Delete Methods"])
@app.put("/items", tags=["Put Methods"])
@app.post("/items", tags=["Post Methods"])
@app.get("/items", tags=["Get Methods"])
async def handle_items():
    return
```

This will give the same look without repetition

[image]

Comment: Also worth noting that tags can be put directly on `APIRouter` objects too